# How to offset all animation curves in FBX files to a zero frame

Tags: animation, scripting, export, maya, fbx

I've got a pack of animation files with skeleton in FBX format, I try to make a script, with which I can offset all animation curves to a zero frame, because all files have a different animation range (1923-1973, 4853-4953 and etc.)

I've never made scripts, thats why I used the chat GPT to do this task, but all my attempts were unsuccessfully.
This was the last my attempt:

```py
import os
import glob
import maya.cmds as cmds

folder_path = "С:/123"

fbx_files = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.fbx")

for file_path in fbx_files:
    cmds.file(file_path, open=True, force=True)
    offset_value = cmds.findKeyframe(time=(1, None), which="first")
    cmds.keyframe(edit=True, timeChange=-offset_value)
    export_path = os.path.join(
        folder_path, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0] + "_offset.fbx"
    )
    cmds.file(
        export_path, force=True, options="v=0;", type="FBX export", pr=True, es=True
    )

cmds.file(force=True, newFile=True)
```

After I had played the sript, the Import Window has appeared and that's it
No errors, just the import window

Comment: You should give us more information about the unsuccessful attempts. Do you get error messages, post error messages here and please edit your code in a way it is displayed correctly.

Comment: @haggikrey After I had played the sript, the Import Window has appeared and that's it No errors, just the import window
Edited the code